# no overload for method "ToString" takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a data reader to read the datas from database. 
I am reading TotalPrice from sales table. 
I would like to show the total price as 2 decimal place.

The code is something link that:

```
TotalPrice.Text = myReader["TotalPrice"].ToString("N2");
```

However i encounted this error: no overload for method "ToString" takes 1 arguments
What's wrong with the code?

Comment: What type is the TotalPrice column?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming that TotalPrice is a Decimal column, and that myReader is a DataReader:

```
TotalPrice.Text = myReader.GetDecimal(myReader.GetOrdinal("TotalPrice")).ToString("N2");
```

The idea here is that myReader's indexer (what you are using when you call `myReader["TotalPrice"]`) returns an Object.  It has to, since it doesn't know at compile time what type the column is.  By using `.GetDecimal()`, you are assuring that you get a Decimal value back, or an error.

The `.ToString` overload that takes a format string is declared on Decimal, not on Object.  Object's .`ToString` takes no arguments.

The inner call to GetOrdinal returns the field's index given the name- if you are doing this in a loop for multiple data rows, you'd probably want to cache that in a variable.

Answer (score 10):

String.Format() will do the trick. F2 is fixed-point notation with 2 decimal places.

```
TotalPrice.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", (double)myReader["TotalPrice"]);
```