# Set DateTimePicker Control to format YYYYMMDD?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I am putting together a simple C# Windows Forms Application. I am setting my DateTimePicker control on load to the current DateTime, example "**11/12/2013 9:49:49 AM**". I then use this value in a query to my 400 system, but I am getting an error because the field I query against the DateTimePicker Controls value is in format 'YYYYMMDD'.

How do I format the value of my DateTimePicker Control to 'YYYYMMDD' to use it in my query?

Comment: dateTime.ToString() has many different options as well. Like MMMM will display only the month, as well as DDDD showing the day. hh:mm:ss tt will show the time with AM/PM. HH:MM:SS will show military time (capitol). @Tobberoth has the correct answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, if your control is named `dtpDate`, you should use something like this (using the `Value` property of the control):

```
string selectDateAsString = dtpDate.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily format the datetime into a string like the one you want:

```
 the_date_time.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: When I try `string formattedDate = dtpDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");` I receive: "No overload for method 'ToSTring' takes 1 arguments".

Answer (score 1):

you need to get the DateTime value from the date time picker then do tostring() on that with the format.

```
string formateddate = dtpDate.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: When I try `string formattedDate = dtpDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");` I receive: "No overload for method 'ToSTring' takes 1 arguments".

Answer (score 1):

Post format your date:

`string formattedDate = MyDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd")`

if directly from the DateTimePicker control use:

`string formattedDate = MyDateTime.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd")`

Comment: When I try `string formattedDate = dtpDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");` I receive: "No overload for method 'ToSTring' takes 1 arguments".

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic you need to get the  `DateTime` value from the date time picker then do tostring() on that.

Comment: @DROPtableusers, `string formattedDate = dtpDate.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");` did it! Thanks!

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic glad you got it. I edited my answer to reflect below.

Answer (score 0):

@Analytic Lunatic please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091177/no-overload-for-method-tostring-takes-1-arguments) for the error you are getting.. I think this will solve the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

```
string dt = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```