# ItemArray to string with format is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, string-formatting, datarow

I have a `DataTable` with several `DataRow` that I want to format in a new `DataTable` but I've found a problem when I try to format some rows:

```
DataTable ret = functionThatGetsaDataTableUsingSQL(); //Original DataTable
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //Final DataTable
foreach (DataRow dr in ret.Rows)
{
    DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();
    for (int j = 0; j < dr.ItemArray.Length; j++)
    {
        if (j == 14) row[j] = dr.ItemArray[j].ToString("C2");
        else row[j] = dr.ItemArray[j];
    }
}
```

The `row[j] = dr.ItemArray[j].ToString("C2");` doesn't work saying `No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments`

I tried to simplify the code as much as I could in order to focus just in the formatting part.

How can I format this value? I know I can cast a `Convert.ToDecimal()` before using the `ToString("C2")` but is that the ONLY way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no overload for method "ToString" takes 1 arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091177/no-overload-for-method-tostring-takes-1-arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ItemArray` is an `object[]`. `Object.ToString` has no parameter. I guess it's actually a currency value. Then use the `DataRow.Field` extension method to cast it:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ret.Rows)
{
    DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();
    for (int j = 0; j < dr.ItemArray.Length; j++)
    {
        if (j == 14) 
            row[j] = dr.Field<decimal>(j).ToString("C2"); // use the correct type
        else 
            row[j] = dr.ItemArray[j];
    }
}
```

Here's an optimized version, the [`ItemArray`-property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray(v=vs.110).aspx) has additional overhead since the getter always creates a new array(as you can see [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataRow.cs,c49b336f59c8f808,references)):

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ret.Rows)
{
    DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();
    foreach(DataColumn col in ret.Columns)
    {
        if (col.Ordinal == 14)
            row.SetField(col.Ordinal, dr.Field<decimal>(col).ToString("C2")); // use the correct type
        else
            row.SetField(col.Ordinal, dr[col]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The Field is a decimal value that I want to convert to a currency one. Either way that solved the question I had. Just to know: Is there any difference between getting a value using `ItemArray[i]` and `Field<type>(i)`? Just asking since it's a loop that will be looped for at least a thousand iterations.

Comment: @MiquelColl: use either the `DataRow` indexer or the `Field`-method. The [`ItemArray`-property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray(v=vs.110).aspx) has additional overhead since the getter always creates a new array. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataRow.cs,c49b336f59c8f808,references

Comment: @MiquelColl: i've edited my answer to show an approach without ItemArray. Instead of `SetField` you can also use `row[index]=`. The former is nicer if you have nullable types.

Comment: I do have some nullable types so the `SetField` sounds like a great tool. I have some work ahead changing so many `ItemArray`...

Answer (score 1):

C2 means it coverts into currency up to 2 decimal place, but what it will convert if you place directly string say "jkld" , so it is mandatory to letting know the compiler your source data type and once it is sure that it is of type double then it will accept  like this

Correct way

```
double myPrice;
myPrice.ToString("C2");
```

This is the theoretical answer , but you should know and in future you don't get confused, Happy Coding :)

Comment: Well, I actually said in my question I know that a decimal/double would be able to be formatted but I wanted to know if there was a way to omit a cast or Convert. Thanks either way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string.Format on anything.

```
string.Format("{0:C2}", o);
```

will compile for any type and value of o. To take advantage of this, your code would be changed as follows:

```
DataTable ret = functionThatGetsaDataTableUsingSQL(); //Original DataTable
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //Final DataTable
foreach (DataRow dr in ret.Rows)
{
    DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();
    for (int j = 0; j < dr.ItemArray.Length; j++)
    {
        if (j == 14) row[j] = string.Format("{0:C2}", dr.ItemArray[j]);
        else row[j] = dr.ItemArray[j];
    }
}
```

EDIT: That doesn't mean this is the best way - the answer that uses the Field method is probably better because it is both faster and more explicit.

My method would be more suitable if you were going to apply this format to various floating point (or even integer) types, and you didn't know what types they would be at the time of writing the code.