# Format the response from the Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API runs a stored procedure and returns the records from the table.The record includes the int field called CounterSeq

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string Account)
{
 // other code for connecting to the SQL seerver and calling the stored procedure
 reader = command.ExecuteReader(); 
 List<QueryResult>qresults = new List<QueryResult>();
   while (reader.Read())
   {
       QueryResult qr = new QueryResult();
       qr.AccountID = reader["AccountID"].ToString();
       qr.CounterSeq = reader["CounterSeq"].ToString();
       qresults.Add(qr);
   }
   DbConnection.Close();
   return Ok(qresults);
```

The format of the CounterSeq in the response should be 001. If I add he below statement like

```
  qr.CounterSeq ="00"+ reader["CounterSeq"].ToString();
```

But with this even for the two digit it shows like "0012" but it needs to be "012" how can I approach this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [PadLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 qr.CounterSeq = reader["CounterSeq"].ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
```

> Returns a new string of a specified length in which the beginning of the current string is padded with spaces or with a specified Unicode character.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`qr.CounterSeq =reader["CounterSeq"].ToString("0000");`

Comment: It throws the Error 1 No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: I have visual studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
qr.CounterSeq = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("CounterSeq")).ToString("D4");
```

Here an answer for the error with the ToString with 1 arguments:
[no overload for method "ToString" takes 1 arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091177/no-overload-for-method-tostring-takes-1-arguments)

You can read more about the the decimal ("D") format specifier here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx